# How do you add a translucent (half transparent) rectangle anywhere in a html page?

Tags: css, text, opacity, transparent, rectangles

I really want to know how to add a half-transparent rectangle in the middle of my page and not cover all my text.

I tried to add white backgrounds and make the opacity lower:

p.a { float: right; margin-right: 500px; background-color:skyblue; -moz-opacity: 0.7; -khtml-opacity: 0.7; opacity: 0.7; text-align-last; } p.w { background-color:skyblue; -moz-opacity: 0.7; -khtml-opacity: 0.7; opacity: 0.7; text-align-last; }

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried absolute position?
That's how you place an element anywhere in your page.
As for the opacity how about like this.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  
  .rectangle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    background-color: rgba(247,30,28,0.5);//0.5=half
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;//anywhere you want
    right: 30%; // anywhere you want
      //left & bottom 
    color: white;
  }
}
```